# Kernel module for create hostapd on android things

Tags: wifi-hotspot, kernel, android-things

I am trying to create an access point on [Android Things for raspberry pi 3](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/download.html), the `hostapd configuration`:

```
cat > data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf << EOF
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/hostapd
ssid=myid
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
EOF
```

I have the following errors on logcat when call `/system/bin/hostapd -e /data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf`

output:

```
E hostapd : Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported on transport endpoint)

I hostapd : rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device

W hostapd : wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
```

If I write `lsmod` I Have the following error:

```
lsmod: No file /proc/modules: No such file or directory
```

So what is the correct `driver=` value to create the ap?

Comment: check if the kernel has enabled support for the nl80211 driver as build in module

Comment: Android's built-in `hostapd` is problematic (may be built without certain features). Use a custom built binary, that works.